# Парсинг вложенных списков bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

```html
<ul class="nav-lvl2-list">
  <li class="nav-lvl2-item   ">
    <a class="nav-lvl2-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/griby-isg24/" aria-label="Грибы">
      <span class="nav-lvl2-item-name">Грибы</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-lvl2-item has-nav  ">
    <a class="nav-lvl2-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/" aria-label="Овощи">
      <span class="nav-lvl2-item-name">Овощи</span>
      <span class="nav-lvl2-toggle js-nav-toggle"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="js-nav nav-lvl3" style="display: none">
      <ul class="nav-lvl3-list">
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/drugie-ovoshchi-isg570/" aria-label="Другие овощи">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Другие овощи</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/imbir-isg571/" aria-label="Имбирь">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Имбирь</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/kabachok-tsukini-isg572/" aria-label="Кабачок\цукини">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Кабачок\цукини</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/kapusta-isg573/" aria-label="Капуста">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Капуста</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/kartofel-isg574/" aria-label="Картофель">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Картофель</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/kukuruza-isg575/" aria-label="Кукуруза">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Кукуруза</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/luk-isg576/" aria-label="Лук">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Лук</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/morkov-isg577/" aria-label="Морковь">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Морковь</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/ogurets-isg578/" aria-label="Огурец">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Огурец</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/perets-isg579/" aria-label="Перец">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Перец</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/redis-redka-isg580/" aria-label="Редис, редька">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Редис, редька</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/selderey-isg582/" aria-label="Сельдерей">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Сельдерей</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/tomat-isg583/" aria-label="Томат">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Томат</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-lvl3-item ">
          <a class="nav-lvl3-link" href="/catalog/ovoshchi-frukty-yagody-griby-zelen-isg187/ovoshchi-isg274/chesnok-isg584/" aria-label="Чеснок">
            <span class="nav-lvl3-item-name">Чеснок</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Я получаю с сайта вот такой вложенный список с категориями. В нем встречаются элементы `li` с разными классами. В случае если есть вложенность дальше у элемента дописывается класс `has-nav`. Мне надо получить активные ссылки на категории.

В случае, когда нет `has-nav`, эта ссылка сразу находится в этом `li`. Если класс есть эти ссылки находятся уже в `<div class="js-nav nav-lvl3" style="display: none">` в котором  есть другой `ul` со всеми ссылками.

Я не понимаю как написать условие, что если `<li class="nav-lvl2-item">`, то мне сразу в этом теге надо брать ссылку. А если есть класс `has-nav` надо идти дальше во вложенный список и брать ссылки оттуда.

Пытался так:

```py
for el in resonse.find_all("ul",class_='nav-lvl2-list'):
    if el.find('li', class_='has-nav'):
        print(el)
```

но у меня все равно выводятся все элементы...
ссылка на [сайт](https://gippo-market.by/catalog/kulinarnaya-produktsiya-isg359/)

Нужны все ссылки как на картинке. Если нет вложенности то это ссылка сразу в этом элементе. Если есть то ссылке находятся в раскрывающемся списке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что нужны ссылки с тех `li`, в которых нет `has-nav`?

Comment: @Jack_oS не совсем. Нужны и от туда и от туда. Но если есть класс `has-nav` то нужные ссылки находятся в следующем вложенном списке. А если нет то ссылка лежит сразу в этом li/

Comment: можно адрес страницы, откуда вы берете этот html? и скрин с категориями, ссылки на которые нужно забрать?

Comment: @Jack_oS добавил. Надеюсь так будет чуть понятнее

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем уверен в чистоте данного способа но вот что получилось

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get('https://gippo-market.by/catalog/kulinarnaya-produktsiya-isg359/',headers=headers)
soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
menu_gippo = soup.find("div", class_="sidebar-menu")

all_li = menu_gippo.find_all("li",class_='nav-item')

for li in all_li:
    for el in li.find_all("li",class_='nav-lvl2-item'):
        if 'has-nav' not in el['class']:
            print(el.find("a")["href"])
        else:
            for href in  el.find_all("li",class_='nav-lvl3-item'):
                print(href.find("a")["href"])
```

проверяю есть ли класс `has-nav` в элементе, если нет то вывожу ссылку с этого `li`.
Если есть то беру ссылки уже из `li` с классом `nav-lvl3-item`